# Recursion: How can i program this expression?

Tags: functions, function-construction, recursion

i have the following expression:

```
Vt[EA_, V0_, Cm_, B_] := EA + (V0 - Cm)*B
```

For `EA` and `Cm` I have a list of the same length for each. `B` is a constant. For the first values of the lists the value for `V0` is known `(3500)`. For the other values of the lists Mathematica should use the respective outcome of the expression for `V0 ( Vt[EA_, V0_, Cm_, B_]=V0 )` and so on. The outcome I want is a list with the same length as the other lists used in the computation +1. So the outcome should be equal to the use of the `FoldList[]` command. But for the use of the `FoldList[]` command iI have one expression that is too much. The work with *Mathematica* is relative new for me so I doen´t know how I can program this kind of recursion.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.
Thank you very much

Comment: FoldList[BerechnungAktieninvestment + (#1 - #2)*1.00003 &, 3500,ListeExposureAktien]. BerechnungAktieninvestment is the list for EA and ListeExposrueAktien ist the list for Cm. 1.00003 is the constant for B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the current computation depends upon the result of the previous step, think `FoldList`. `FoldList` is a fast and efficient function to use for those cases.

Let's look at this for three steps where the inputs are symbolic (tip: don't use upper case symbols, you may end up clashing with system symbols).

```
vt[ea_, v0_, cm_, b_] := ea + (v0 - cm)*b
ea = {ea1, ea2, ea3};
cm = {cm1, cm2, cm3};
```

In the application of `FoldList` we will create a list that consists of `{eaN, cmN}` pairs.

```
FoldList[vt[#2[[1]], #1, #2[[2]], b] &, v0,
    Transpose[Join[{ea, cm}]]] // Column
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

If you study the rows you can see that the `v0` input to the current row is the value output from the previous computation.

Now apply it to a numerical example:

```
v0 = 3500;
ea = {10, 11, 12};
cm = {9, 10, 11};
b = 1.1;

FoldList[vt[#2[[1]], #1, #2[[2]], b] &, v0, 
 Transpose[Join[{ea, cm}]]]

(* {3500, 3850.1, 4235.11, 4658.52} *)
```

Comment: Hello Jack LaVigne,

Comment: The solution is great but i have the problem that i have a set of lists for ea and for cm like a set of 10000 and now i have the problem to create pairs of lists.

Comment: i think i got it i have flatten both set of list and than transpoesed and joined it. it should work now thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
RecurrenceTable[{vt[n + 1] == EA + (vt[n] - Cm)*B, vt[1] == 3500}, vt, {n, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you so if my lists have the legth of 720 i have to use  {n, 1, 720} or  {n, 1, 721}?

Comment: Or gives Mathematica automaticly the length of 721 if i put in the lists for the EA and Cm?